# Drop in control to edit a table

Tags: asp.net

Is there a control I can just drop on a page, and link it to a sql server table that will then list all the rows in the table and let me edit any of the columns?

Also the ability to add, delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net dynamic data, it generates a CRUD interface for your tables.

read more

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data/getting-started-with-dynamic-data

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) control. You can set the connection via `ConnectionString` property, and also utilize the `DeleteCommand` and `InsertCommand` properties.

Using a `GridView`, you can then set the DataSourceID to the ID of your SqlDataSource